# Creating vertical line at the center of li

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have created a html page with `ul` and `li`'s to show some links and set up some background color to the `li`'s. Now I want to add vertical line on the `li`'s.

When I try to set up a image it is coming as shown in *figure 1* but I want it to be as shown in *figure 2*.

**figure 1**

[image]

**figure 2**

[image]

What I have tried so far:

```css
ul#sitemap1 {
  list-style: none;
}

ul#sitemap1 li a {
  background-color: #002163;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#sitemap1 li {
  clear: left !important;
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  padding: 10px !important;
  background: url('/Images/ConnectLine.JPG') no-repeat !important;
  float: inherit;
}

ul#sitemap1 li a:hover {
  background-color: Orange;
}

ul#sitemap2 {
  list-style: none;
}

ul#sitemap2 li a {
  background-color: #002163;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul#sitemap2 li a:hover {
  background-color: Orange;
}

ul#sitemap3 {
  list-style: none;
}

ul#sitemap3 li a {
  background-color: #002163;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul#sitemap3 li a:hover {
  background-color: Orange;
}
```

```html
<h1>Innovations</h1>

<ul id="sitemap1">
  <a href="https://Home.aspx" style="font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none">Home</a>
  <li><a href="https://Services.aspx">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="https:///OC.aspx">Organizational Change</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://kit.aspx">kit</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://Sheets.aspx">Sheets</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="sitemap2">
  <a href="https://Engagement.aspx" style="font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none">Engagement</a>
  <li><a href="https://Ideas.aspx">Ideas</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://WS.aspx">WorkSmart</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="sitemap3">
  <a href="https://Links.aspx" style=" font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none">Related Links</a>
  <li><a href="https://Gotime.aspx">GO-TIME</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There are no "lines" in your demo...what's happened to those?

Comment: Please fix the invalid HTML of <a> directly under <ul>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a pseudo element `::after` in the `a` child of `li`

Note you can only have `li` as direct childs of `ul`. otherwise it is invalid HTML

I tweaked your CSS removing duplicated properties.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 30px
}
ul li a {
  background-color: #002163;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative
}
ul li a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  background: black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  content: ""
}
ul li:last-of-type a::after {
  background: transparent;
  height: 0
}
ul li a:hover {
  background-color: Orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Innovations</h1>

  <ul id="sitemap1">
    <li><a href="https://Home.aspx">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://Services.aspx">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https:///OC.aspx">Organizational Change</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://kit.aspx">kit</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://Sheets.aspx">Sheets</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
  <ul id="sitemap2">
    <li><a href="https://Engagement.aspx">Engagement</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://Ideas.aspx">Ideas</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://WS.aspx">WorkSmart</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="sitemap3">
    <li><a href="https://Links.aspx">Related Links</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://Gotime.aspx">GO-TIME</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help dippas

Comment: @user2314241 you are welcome `:)`, you may look at my edited answer since I tweaked your CSS a bit.

Answer (score 2):

1. I suggest remove the id's form the CSS, no need to duplicate the same CSS just refer to the `ul` tag.
2. You can use `:after` pseudo-element to create the line.
3. Use `:last-child` to remove the line form the last item.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  width: 220px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
ul li:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  background: black;
  width: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  z-index: 100;
}
ul li:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}
ul li a {
  background-color: #002163;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
ul li a:hover {
  background-color: Orange;
}
```

```html
<h1>Innovations</h1>
<ul id="sitemap1"><a href="https://Home.aspx" style="font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none">Home</a>
  <li><a href="https://Services.aspx">Services</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="https:///OC.aspx">Organizational Change</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="https://kit.aspx">kit</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="https://Sheets.aspx">Sheets</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul id="sitemap2"><a href="https://Engagement.aspx" style="font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none">Engagement</a>
  <li><a href="https://Ideas.aspx">Ideas</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="https://WS.aspx">WorkSmart</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul id="sitemap3"><a href="https://Links.aspx" style=" font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none">Related Links</a>
  <li><a href="https://Gotime.aspx">GO-TIME</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this is what am looking for ...thank u so much DaniP

Comment: glad to help @user2314241

Answer (score 0):

Try this, same you could try for sitemap 1 and 3.

```
ul#sitemap2 li::after{
content:'';
border:3px solid #111;
height:50px;
margin-left:110px;
}
```